# geometry package keyval error

Tags: graphics, packages, geometry

Could you help me out solve this problem. After compiling my `.tex` file
I get these two errors.

```
geometry.sty  Package keyval Error: up undefined. \ProcessOptionsKV[p]{Gm} \
graphics.sty File `dvipdfm.def' not found. ...d{ver@\Gin@driver}{\input{\Gin@driver}}{}
  \@ifundefined{ver@\Gin@driver}{\input{\Gin@driver}}{}
```

Thank you
Regards

---

```
\documentclass[rennes1]{phd}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,up=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url,rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{caption} 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{url,rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Définition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
%\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{remarque}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remarque}[chapter]


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.75cm}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


    \Abreviations{Ab}
    \input{Abreviations}
%   \Notations{Notations}
%   \input{Chp0//Notation.tex}
    \listoffigures
    \Introduction{Liste des Figures}
    %fancyhead[R]{\small Liste des Figures}
    \listoftables
    \Introduction{Liste des Tableaux}
    \fancyhead[R]{\small Liste des Tableaux}
    \mainmatter

    %\newpage
    %%%%%%--------------------------------------- Introduction-------------------------- 


%   \include{chap2}
%   \include{chap3}
%   \include{chap4}
%   \include{chap5}
    \Introduction{Introduction} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post such error messages only. I think the error is rather related to the `graphicx` package here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Without a minimal (non-)working example, it's hard to guess. Did you recently update? There was a reorganisation of the graphics drivers last year.

Comment: The first error is about an option `up` which is not defined. So remove it.

Comment: @Bernard sorry i dont know how to include tex excerpt in my question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer up is defined equal to 2cm

Comment: The syntax is `top=2cm`. What is this `phd` class, with option `rennes1`?

Comment: @Bernard it is a specific template given by my institution

Comment: Thank you @Bernard the first error is solved, i still get the 'dvipdfm' error, changes i made on my '.tex' are not taken into consideration

Comment: Can we get it somewhere, just to test if any conflict?

Comment: @Bernard unfortunately it is not available online. i still get the 'dvipdfm' error, changes i made on my '.tex' ado not appear in the output pdf

Comment: 1) you do not need to specify any driver nowadays for the `graphicx` package: it automatically which one is required. 2) In any case, it should be `dvipdfmx`(`dvipdfm` does not exist any more). Do you intend to compile with `pdflatex` or with `latex`?

Comment: @Bernard i'm compiling with pdflatex. shall i remove all the graphicx package ?

Comment: Not at all (unless you have no figure to load). Simply it does not require any option.

Comment: I have a lot of figures. what is the difference between graphics and graphicx packages ? which one is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I reorganised  and spring-cleaned your preamble. Avoid loading the same packages multiple times, and note that:

- `aeguill` has been obsolete for more tha 20 years.
- You should load `inputenc` with option `utf8`, as all modern editors and all modern O.S.s understand `Unicode`.
- Needless to load `color` if you load `xcolor`, nor `url` as you load `hyperref`.
- The `subfigure` package is obsolete and no more maintained. The `subfigure` environment, from `subcaption` is recommended instead.
- `epsfig` is obsolete; `graphicx` does the job.

  ```
  \documentclass[table, french]{book}%[rennes1]{phd}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{newlfont}
  \usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, bbm}
  \usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{comment}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.75cm}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \usepackage{titling}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
  \usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
  \setcellgapes{1pt}
  \makegapedcells
  \usepackage{supertabular, longtable}
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{caption, subcaption}
  % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
  \usepackage{boxedminipage2e}
  \usepackage[centertags]{mathtools}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{cite, notoccite}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
  \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
  \newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}

  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{defn}{Définition}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
  %\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
  \theoremstyle{remarque}
  \newtheorem{rem}{Remarque}[chapter]

  \usepackage{hyperref}
  %\bibliographystyle{plain}

  \begin{document}
  ```

Comment: +1 for "spring-cleaned your preamble", but where it is now? and `hyperref` should be very last in preamble (with rare exceptions)

Comment: @Zarko: Oops! I *thought* of posting it! I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernard Could you please post the reorganized preamble. Thank you so much

Comment: 'Tis done, milady!

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard sorry but pdflatex.exe did not succeed with a very large logfile of 2.24MB couldnt even display

Comment: Well, as usual, a minimal (almost) compilable example is necessary. I guess the problem lies in one of the files you input/include, which I do not have access to. Comment all but one to try localise  the defective file, to begin with.

Comment: The same .tex files compiled successfully in my friend's computer. Does this mean that i have problem with my miktex distribution Miktex version 2.9.6200 on windows 7 @Bernard . How to include '.tex' code into a comment ?

Comment: If you compile with no file loaded, just any small text, does it compile?

Comment: It compiles with errors. but i obtained an output pdf file.  i tried \begin{document}   hello world \end{document}

Comment: Could you post the .log file?

Comment: I did sir only for lines where it was mentioned fatal. @Bernard Thank you so much for you support